# Connecting 220V mains switches (with on-indicator lights) to 12V COB LED lights in series

Tags: power-supply, led, switches, mains, light

I wil be switching COB Led lights (each one rated at 12V, 200mA) individually with these switches.

One end of each of the  60 COB LED lights is connected to 12V, the other end to 60 of these 220V mains switches with lights in series. So all 60 leds are connected in parallel, and all 60 switches are connected in series. The LED adapter will be a 12V 4Ah constant voltage adapter.

Q1. Will these switches turn on the led lights at full power? Or will the light diode act like a resistors and makes the LEDs go dimmer?

Q2. Will the on-indicator lights of the switches light ip or not, in this 12V system?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you wire the switches.

I'd guess that the two silver terminals are the actual switch contacts, and the brass terminal is one end of the light.  The other end of the light is probably connected to the center terminal (but that's only a guess...)

If you just use the switch contacts (silver terminals) the LEDs should light at full brightness.  The light included in the switch will not light with only 12 volts, if it is intended to work on 220 V.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. Will these switches turn on the led lights at full power? Or will
>   the light diode act like a resistors and makes the LEDs go dimmer?

Full power, assuming the switch is connected between the LED cathode and ground.

> Q2. Will the on-indicator lights of the switches light up or not, in
>   this 12V system?

No, not likely.